# Module validate_email throws None when checking valid email address

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying the code below to check if an email address is valid and if it exists.

The validation part works but when checking if it exists, it throws None on an any email address.

```
from validate_email_address import validate_email

email_address = 'krian.cardons@gmail.com'

is_valid = validate_email(email_address) # Check if email address is in correct format
print ('Email', email_address, 'is valid:', is_valid)

is_valid = validate_email(email_address, verify=True) # Check if email address exists
print ('Email', email_address, 'exists:', is_valid)
```

Comment: Are you using this [validate_email](https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/) package?

Comment: The import statement should be `from validate_email import validate_email`. And FYI, there are [a lot of open issues](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+none) on that package's Github page regarding returning `None` when checking for existence. You might want to participate in those discussions. It seems it returns `None` when a [socket exception is raised](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/blob/master/validate_email.py#L176).